# nvarchar(max) - how to speed up getting only meaningful string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a table with a column with `Nvarchar(Max)`. The Column is 90% percent of the time having a string length between 255 and 500. Some go well over 22000 which aren't required as its XML of something that the business wont ever use for reporting purpose. Anyways to cut a long story short was the best way to trim out all the excess bulk. I have tried the usual

```
left(column,500)
```

and

```
substring(column,1,500)
```

I have set the destination column to be 500 length.
However loading the table from source to target destination takes a while just because of that column alone. I am doing the in SSIS in the Source. I also gone to the output column and ignored truncation. Is there anyway I can reduce the time take loading this column. These methods seem to take as much as loading the full length. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you should make a table that only houses instances of this column when it is longer than a certain length.  Then just store a foreign key and maybe a bit to denote if the data is stored in the new LongStrings table or in the original column.  This is a pretty ugly approach but you wouldn't need to pull in all that garbage every time you query that main table.  You can also do some sort of full-text indexing to search through that data faster.

Comment: Do you want to actually truncate the field, or are you only looking for the records where the field is in the 200-500 character range?

Comment: Ideally keep the content of the field but restrict it to bring back a maximum of 500 length character. Suppose the ones that are longer aren't really necessary if they are xmls as they can be mammoth .

Comment: PS this table records all activities of all types, it's a crm system that just sparingly varies in content some are meaning and some aren't. The bigger string length ones are xmls which aren't and can be excluded i suppose as per business analyst had mentioned

Answer (score 1):

`NVARCHAR(MAX)` *(even when using a function like `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT`)* will cost a lot of memory and will fill up your buffers quickly. Check the `DefaultBufferMaxSize` and also the properties `BLOBTempStoragePath` and `BufferTempStoragePath` setting them to an optimal value might increase the performance but note that you have so configure them accordingly because it is like a double edged sword.

Also If Source and Destination are on differents servers, the network could also be an issue because all data has to to from your SQL server via the network to your SSIS server. You could try changing the [Network Packet Size](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/04/performance-best-practice-network.html)

**More info are provided in these links**

- [Set BLOBTempStoragePath and BufferTempStoragePath to Fast Drives](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlperf/2007/05/01/set-blobtempstoragepath-and-buffertempstoragepath-to-fast-drives/)
- [Troubleshooting Package Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141031(v=sql.90).aspx)
- [Perfomance Issue with NVarchar(MAX) in SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1f3f7e30-e811-4f24-b99a-de76578ed68b/perfomance-issue-with-nvarcharmax-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)